# Xcode 5.1 breaks some tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest, xcode5.1

Since updating to Xcode 5.1, I have been encountering errors while attempting to run unit tests (XCTestSuite). When I run an individual test method, I get the error `Error while reading test scope bundle` on the console and no result. When I run the full implementation of the test file, I see:

```
Unable to get entitlements for client task. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (POSIX error -1 - Unknown error: -1)"
```

Then the tests appear to start running as expected.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Xcode 5.1

Comment: I'm seeing this as well in Xcode CI for subsets of the full unit tests. Super annoying.

Comment: I'm seeing the 'entitlements' issue as well, but only when the tests are run on a device. It occurs for both full and individual test run. Tests run fine on the simulator.

Note that I only see this problem for tests that call into FXKeyChain a wrapper for the KeyChain.

Comment: Found a similar question with an answer that solved it for me (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22561810/1685851)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a test target named something like MyApp Tests (notice the whitespace) try changing the product name on that target to MyApp_Tests instead. The product name will then be MyApp_Tests.xctest instead of MyApp Tests.xctest.

Seems like this is a path issue.

Comment: This did indeed solve the test scope bundle issue. I'm still seeing the second, entitlements issue when i run the tests however.

Comment: I think that must be unrelated because we didn't run into that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to run single tests by using hjaltij's method but adding a new test target worked for me

**TestNavigator > Add New Test Target (Plus Button)**

Then create new test classes under this target