# XCode unit testing: Error while reading test scope bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I'm receiving *Error while reading test scope bundle !* while running a Unit Test in XCode 5.
No test runs.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332859/xcode-5-1-breaks-some-tests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the issue. Appears that I must run all tests after creating a new test. Not possible to run a fresh test individually from the gui until all tests have run.

Comment: No matter either fresh or old test (/s) I still get this error. I have about 8 test cases in my bundle and when I try to disable all and run a single test, I get this error. I tried running all tests first, and then running only one without luck.

Comment: I got it solved by setting "Build Active Architecture Only" in the test target to No

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by setting "Build Active Architecture Only" in the test target to No

Answer (score 0):

Delete the built app from the simulator. Its bundle can get out of whack and Xcode can't fix it for some reason.